Enter a personal identification number
In this challenge your code should allow the user to enter a four digit PIN.
Rules
If the user types a digit, your code should output a * symbol.  If the user presses backspace it should delete the previous * symbol. If there are no *s to delete it should do nothing and wait for the next key press. All other key presses should be ignored.
The code has to be interactive, that is it updates the output after each key press and doesn't wait for return to be pressed (which should be ignored anyway).
Once 4 digits have been entered, the code should quit.

Why the downvote?

Isn't the backspace rule redundant?

@bzr why would it be redundant?

What about 'delete'? Should those also mandatory be ignored, or should/could those work, just like backspace?

@KevinCruijssen It should be ignored.

HTML, 150 148 134 100 94 84 80 77 76 bytes


<input type=password onkeydown=c=event.key;return!(value[3]||c[5]!='p'&!++c)



-54 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.
-10 bytes thanks to @l4m2 and @jdt.
-4 bytes thanks to @jdt again.
I'm still trying to find a browser that uses asterisk for password-fields instead of bullets (the four browsers I had installed - Chrome; Firefox; Edge; Opera - unfortunately all use bullets). But certain old browser versions defintely used asterisks for password input-fields, so it's assumed this snippet is used in one of those browsers / versions.
Explanation:

<input - Input box
type=password - Of type password, so every valid character that's typed (aka digits) will be shown as asterisks in certain browsers (in most modern browsers they'll be shown as bullet points instead, though)
onkeydown= - Capture and handle key-presses
c=event.key; - Save the keypress as character in variable c, since we'll use it twice later on
return - Return a boolean:
!(...) - By negating the following bits:
value[3] - Stop after the fourth digit has been entered
|| - Otherwise:
c[5]!='p' - If c is NOT a backspace - The sixth character is a 'p', which only applies to the unprintables 'Backspace' and 'PageUp', of which the second won't input or remove anything anyway
&!++c - nor a digit (e.key range ['0','9']) - The ++e.key will fail for any non-digit value, becoming NaN.

Known issues:

Shift + digits (aka !@#$%&*()) seem to work again unfortunately, even though I explicitly fixed that in my initial 150 bytes version. EDIT: It works again since the 77 bytes version that uses e.key instead of e.which to check whether it's a digit.
'preparation characters' (aka '"`~^) still seem to work unfortunately (even beyond four characters)..


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

ZX Spectrum 48K/128K Basic, 121 bytes
   2 LET a=NOT PI
   3 IF INKEY$<>"" THEN GO TO PI
   4 LET a$=INKEY$: IF a$="" THE
N GOTO VAL "4"
   5 LET a=a+(a$>="0" AND a$<="9
")-(CODE a$=VAL "12" AND a)
   6 PRINT AT NOT PI,NOT PI;"***
*"(TO a),
   7 IF a<PI THEN GO TO PI

The above is how the program lists on screen as the ZX Spectrum's screen is 32 characters wide. The byte count was calculated by subtracting the system variables for the end and start of the program; this will be one less than the save file length as an empty program has a save file length of 1. Unfortunately I was using an online emulator which only has a save snapshot option, so you'll have to retype this yourself to test it. When typing this in 128K Basic you may notice the editor adding extra spaces but these do not take up any extra bytes, while when typing this in 48K Basic you need to ensure you use all of the tokens including <>, >= and <=. Explanation:
   2 LET a=NOT PI

Start with no digits entered. (Literal numbers cost their length plus six bytes so when golfing you need to use any means possible to avoid them.)
   3 IF INKEY$<>"" THEN GO TO PI

Wait until the current key is released. (Yes, the line number was chosen so that the GO TO could be as short as possible.)
   4 LET a$=INKEY$: IF a$="" THEN GOTO VAL "4"

Wait until a key is pressed, capturing its value in a$.
   5 LET a=a+(a$>="0" AND a$<="9")-(CODE a$=VAL "12" AND a)

Adjust the number of digits according to whether the key was a digit or the code for delete (which is what the ZX Spectrum calls backspace). Note that AND evaluates both its arguments and returns the first if the second is nonzero.
   6 PRINT AT NOT PI,NOT PI;"****"(TO a),

Output the corresponding number of *s. The , is normally used to jump to the next tab stop, but conveniently it outputs a space first, which will delete the last * if the last key was the delete key.
   7 IF a<PI THEN GO TO PI

Repeat until 4 digits have been input. (PI is doing a lot of heavy lifting in this program!)
This program could also be adapted to run on the ZX81 but you would need to split line 4 up into two lines as the ZX81 only accepts one statement per line except in IF...THEN statements. This would increase the byte count by 4.

Java 21, 212 bytes
A graphical solution with AWT. The output is displayed in the window title.
At least on Windows 10, you need to resize the window so you can see the title, or look at the taskbar etc.

new java.awt.Frame(){{addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter(){int j,c;public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e){c=e.getKeyChar();setTitle("*".repeat(j+=j>3?0:47<c&&c<58?1:j>0&&c<9?-1:0));}});}}::show

The code is a Runnable (or similar) method reference.
Commented
new java.awt.Frame() {{ // Create a new anonymous Frame subclass
    addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        int j, c; // j = title length, c = the current character
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
            c = e.getKeyChar();
            setTitle("*".repeat(
                j += j > 3 // if the length is 4, don't modify it
                    ? 0
                    : 47 < c && c < 58 // if the character is a digit,
                        ? 1            // add one asterisk
                        : j > 0 && c < 9 // key 8 is the backspace and other
                                         // control chars don't get this event
                            ? -1 // remove an asterisk if there are any
                            : 0
            ));
        }
    });
}}::show // show the frame when called


I need to remember that ::show. Usually I put the show(); inside the initalizer-block of the Frame, which is 1 byte longer. :) As for some small things to golf: both && can be & for -2 bytes. And you can use a loose import java.awt.*;, so the java.awt. can be removed from the Frame, KeyAdapter, and KeyEvent.

QBasic, 83 bytes
CLS
1c=ASC(INPUT$(1))
d=d-(d>0)*(c=8)+(c>47)*(c<58)
CLS
?STRING$(d,42)
IF d<4GOTO 1

Try it at Archive.org!
Explanation
CLS

Clear the screen.
1

Line number (used as a GOTO target later).
c = ASC(INPUT$(1))

Read one character from user input, get its ASCII code, and store that in c. Digits are 48-57; backspace is 8.
d = d - (d > 0) * (c = 8) + (c > 47) * (c < 58)

Update d, the number of digits entered so far. (Like all numeric variables in QBasic, it starts out with a value of 0.)

If d > 0 and c = 8 are both truthy (-1), multiply them to get 1 and subtract that from d. That is, if there are any digits and the user presses backspace, remove one digit.
If c > 47 and c < 58 are both truthy (-1), multiply them to get 1 and add that to d. That is, if the user presses a digit key, add one digit.

All other keypresses have no effect on d.
CLS
PRINT STRING$(d, 42)

Clear the screen and print a string of d asterisks (ASCII code 42).
IF d < 4 THEN GOTO 1

If the number does not have four digits yet, go back to line 1 and input another character. Otherwise, the program is over and halts.
The leading CLS is perhaps not necessary. Without it, the screen initially shows the results of the last program run, and it is only cleared once the user presses their first key. Since this includes any key, not just the number & backspace keys, I thought it probably ran afoul of "All other key presses should be ignored," so I included an initial clear-screen just in case.

x86 .COM opcode, 40 bytes
Not placing on left-to corner saves: https://i.sstatic.net/GsmDekFQ.png
    org 100h
    mov bx, 0AE00h
    mov ds, bx
f:  mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    cmp al, 8
    je  bksp
    sub al, '0'
    cmp al, 10
    jnb f
    mov [bx], byte '*'
t:  inc bx
    inc bx
    cmp bl, 8
    jb  f
    ret
bksp:
    sub bl, 2
    jc  t
    mov [bx], byte ' '
    jmp f

00000000: bb00 ae8e dbb4 00cd 163c 0874 112c 303c  .........<.t.,0<
00000010: 0a73 f2c6 072a 4343 80fb 0872 e8c3 80eb  .s...*CC...r....
00000020: 0272 f3c6 0720 ebdd                      .r... ..


HTML, 78 bytes


<input onkeydown=return!value[3]&&(c=event.which^48)-56&&![value+=9<c?'':'*']>



From Kevin Cruijssen's solution, doesn't handle Shift well

But how can I test it??

I don't know you but I used Windows xp 32-bit to test it

@anatolyg https://i.sstatic.net/GsmDekFQ.png

Zsh, 94 87 bytes
Lost 3 bytes to fix a bug (if first key is backspace, a[1]= makes $a an array). Saved 3 bytes by not using %s in the printf statement, then 7 more by switching from while to for.
a=
for ((;$#a<4;))
{read -sk1 k
case $k {$'\C-?')a[1]=;;[0-9])a+=*;}
printf '\r\e[K'$a}


asterisks=
# $#foo: length of $foo
for ((;$#asterisks < 4;)); {
    # -s: silent/noecho, -k 1: one keypress
    read -s -k 1 key
    case $key {
        # backspace: delete first character from asterisks string
        $'\C-?') asterisks[1]= ;;
        [0-9])   asterisks+=*
    }
    # \r: start of line, \e[K: clear to end of line
    printf '\r\e[K'$asterisks
}


C (Turbo C), 89 88 bytes
main(n,c){for(;write(1,"\r    \r****",(c-8?c>47&c<58?++n:n:n>1?--n:n)+5)<10;)c=getch();}

Interactive Demo

On the interactive demo, when I press the Delete key, it displays an asterisk. I'm not sure if this is a feature of the demo or the code, though.

The interactive demo is a bit wonky, but it works correctly when compiled with msvc in windows.

R + cli, 91 84 80 bytes
while(F<4){cat(c('\b \b','*')[x<-(nchar(k<-cli::keypress())>8&F)-k%in%0:9]);F=F-x}

(\b represents a single 08 byte in the source code)
The R cli (command line interface) library indicates that keypress() "currently only works at Linux/Unix and OSX terminals, and at the Windows command line", so unfortunately I don't know of an online site where this will run correctly.  It runs fine in my OSX terminal.
keypress() returns the character representing the key pressed, or a string representing 'special' keys, of which "backspace" is the only one with >8 characters, so nchar()>8 saves 4 bytes compared to =="backspace" and 3 bytes compared to grepl("ba",).

TurboWarp, 424 bytes
Try it here.
Key-presses are really hard to manage well.
NOTE: This will not work in Scratch, because backspace is only detectable in TurboWarp.
NOTE: In the scratchblocks version and the picture, I used a custom block containing 1 argument. This was because I had to actually use the block rather than leave it as a function, and scratchblocks needs something in a custom block to recognize it as one. The project linked to will use an empty block, however.
edit: translating into scratchblocks is HARD
define(
set[i v]to(0
repeat until<(i)>(9
if<key(i)pressed?>then
set[x v]to(join(x)[*
stop[this script v]
end
change[i v]by(1
end
when gf clicked
set[x v]to[
repeat until<(length of(x))=(4
if<<key(any v)pressed?>and<not<key(backspace v)pressed?>>>then
(
end
if<key(backspace v)pressed?>then
set[j v]to((length of(x))-(2
set[x v]to[
repeat until<(length of(x))>(j
set[x v]to(join(x)[*
end
end
wait until<not<key(any v)pressed?



Ruby, 79 bytes
Contains unprintable characters. (See ungolfed code).
i=0
(c=STDIN.getch
c==??i>0&&(i-=1
$><<" "):/\d/=~c&&(i+=1
$><<?*))while i<4

Ungolfed
i = 0
(
  c = STDIN.getch
  c == "\x7f"
    ? i > 0 && (
        i -= 1
        $> << "\x08 \x08"
      )
    : /\d/ =~ c && (
        i += 1
        $> << "*"
    )
) while i < 4


Nim, 123 bytes
Includes non-printable chars:
import terminal;let w=writeStyled
var n=0;while n<4:n+=(case getch()
of'0'..'9':(w"*";1)
of'':(w"[D[J";-int n>0)
else:0)

Version without non-printable chars, 129 bytes:
import terminal;let w=writeStyled
var n=0;while n<4:n+=(case getch()
of'0'..'9':(w"*";1)
of'\x7F':(w "\e[D\e[J";-int n>0)
else:0)


It's great to see a nim answer!

Rust, 484 468 458 426 403 bytes
use std::io::{stdin,stdout,Write};use termion::{clear,cursor::Left,event::Key::{Backspace,Char},input::TermRead,raw::IntoRawMode};fn main(){let(mut o,mut l)=(stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap(),0);for k in stdin().keys(){match k.unwrap(){Char(c)=>{if c.is_digit(10){write!(o,"*").unwrap();l+=1}}Backspace=>{write!(o,"{}{}",Left(1),clear::AfterCursor).unwrap();l-=1}_=>()}o.flush().unwrap();if l>3{break}}}

This solution uses Termion, and so doesn't support Windows.
I'm new to terminal manipulation so this probably isn't the most concise way to do this.
Ungolfed:
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use termion::{
    clear,
    cursor::Left,
    event::Key::{Backspace, Char},
    input::TermRead,
    raw::IntoRawMode,
};
fn main() {
    let (mut o, mut l) = (stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap(), 0);
    for k in stdin().keys() {
        match k.unwrap() {
            Char(c) => {
                if c.is_digit(10) {
                    write!(o, "*").unwrap();
                    l += 1
                }
            }
            Backspace => {
                write!(o, "{}{}", Left(1), clear::AfterCursor).unwrap();
                l -= 1
            }
            _ => (),
        }
        o.flush().unwrap();
        if l > 3 {
            break;
        }
    }
}


This is really hard in rust!

Python, 101 bytes
import sys;s=0
while s<4:
 c=sys.stdin.read(1)
 s+=c.isdigit()-(c=='\x08')
 print("*"*s+'  ',end='\r')

This script only works on a terminal set to raw input mode.
On UNIX, you can achieve this using stty raw.
Windows version, 102 bytes
import msvcrt;s=0
while s<4:
 c=msvcrt.getch()
 s+=c.isdigit()-(c==b'\x08')
 print("*"*s+' ',end='\r')

This second version uses msvcrt, which is only available on Windows, but it does not require raw input mode.

This doesn't quite work. I see the digits I am pressing for example where I should only see *s.

@Simd I've added more details about how to run the script, as well as a second version for Windows.

Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! I found one bug: pressing backspace too many times can make s go negative, requiring multiple digit presses before an asterisk will show up again. (s>0!=c==b'\x08') should fix it for +5 bytes. But then you can save some bytes by putting the loop all on one line with semicolons.



<input type=password onkeydown=e=event;return!(value[3]||!++e.key&e.which!=8)
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/275630/enter-a-personal-identification-number/275634#275634




This doesn't seem to work as needed. It doesn't ignore non digits for example
